# KDE's Force DPI setting

Tags: kde

From the "Fonts - KDE Control Module", I have set "Force fonts DPI" to 96. I'm curious where that setting is stored, because grepping my `~/.config` doesn't turn up anything obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I found it:

```
$ cat .kde/share/config/kcmfonts 
[General]
dontChangeAASettings=true
forceFontDPI=96
```